# value from the ajax page is getting only on second attempt in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Here am not getting value on first click of the `option` tag in `select` box and the value gets if second time the `option` value selected.the same code gets if an `alert` is used inside the `on click`.Here is my code please have a look

```js
if ($(element).is('select')) {

  var item = $(this).val();
  var total1 = $(this).closest('.near').find('.total');
  var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/get_corresponding_quantity";
  $.post(url, {
    item: item
  }, function(data) {

    total1.html(data);
  });


  $(".item1").on('click', function(e)

    {

      e.preventDefault();
      var quantity = $(this).closest('.near').find(".quantity1").val();

      var total = $(this).closest('.near').find(".total1").val();
      alert(total);

      if (parseInt(quantity) > parseInt(total)) {
        $(this).closest('.near').find('.quantity_error').html('<span class="quantity_error_msg">Qty must be smaller than Total!..</span>').show();
        $("#btnCreate").prop('disabled', true);
      } else if (parseInt(quantity) <= parseInt(total)) {

        $(this).closest('.near').find('.quantity_error').hide();
        if ($('.quantity_error:visible').length < 1) {
          $("#btnCreate").prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }

    });


}
```

Here is my view page

```
<select name="item[]" id="item" class="item1" required data-bind="select2data: Helper,class: item"  data-placeholder="Item" data-width="100%">
  <option></option>
  <optgroup label="Uncategorized"></optgroup>
  <?php if(!empty($tools)) {
    foreach ($tools as $tool) {?>
      <option class="itm" value="<?= $tool->id;?>"><?= $tool->tool_name;?></option>
  <?php    } } ?>
</select>
<td style="vertical-align: top" colspan="2" class="quantity"><input type="text" required name="quantity[]" id="quantity" class="regular form-control input-sm quantity1 " onkeyup="value_check(<?php echo $n++;?>)" style="width: 100px; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 0px; line-height: 14px" data-bind="textInput: Debit" /></td>

<td style="vertical-align: top" class="total" ><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" id="total" required class="regular form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 0px; line-height: 14px"  /></td>
```

Comment: Formatting your script it does not match up bracket-wise. Any console errors? Is the html dynamically inserted, then you need to delegate

Comment: The script is running on `document.ready`?

Comment: @Programmer no the script is not running with document.ready

Comment: so when is it running?

Comment: its starting running when a value from select tag is chooses and at that time `($(element).is('select'))` starts

Comment: @mplungjan now i had edited my code

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running only after a value is selected from the select, meaning that the `eventhandler` `$(".item1").on('click', function(e)` is set only after a value is chosen. that's why the event isn't triggered on the first value select.

Move the `eventhandler` to `document.ready` so the event will be triggered also in the first value select.

Comment: i had changed my code as per your idea but still its not getting